# How to get back spaces in administrative names in GADM 4.1

Tags: gadm

I recently downloaded the [GeoJSON of Republic of the Congo](https://gadm.org/download_country.html) and I realized that the data have no spaces for the name fields anymore since version 4.1.

[image]

Is there a simple way to compute them back or is there plan to reintroduce them in 4.2 ?

**EDIT**

This issue is only present in the geojson files, the .gpkg sources still have the spaces available.

Comment: Find and Replace?

Comment: @Hornbydd how does find and replace help? There's nothing to search for, i.e. no spaces.

Comment: You find "republicofcongo" and replace with "republic of congo".

Comment: You do realize that "republicofcongo" is just an example and that I'm looking for a consistent way to replace any names (it's the case for every admin level) for any country? I think that's what user2856 meant by "there is nothing to search for"